# isSupported' of undefined jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, css-animations, keyframe

I have an error when I add a KeyFrame in jQuery with the Github solution.

```
    var $ = jQuery;
      var supportedFlag = $.keyframe.isSupported();
      $.keyframe.define([{
      name: 'rotate',
      '0%': { transform: rotate("0deg")},
      '15%': { transform: rotate("12deg")},
      '30%': { transform: rotate("-12deg")},
      '45%': { transform: rotate("12deg")},
      '60%': { transform: rotate("-12deg")},
      '75%': { transform: rotate("12deg")},
      '90%': { transform: rotate("-12deg")},
      '100%': { transform: rotate("0deg")}
  }]);

      jQuery('.field-name-field-home-link-image .field-items .field-item img').hover(function(){
        jQuery('.field-name-field-home-link-image .field-items .field-item img').parent().parent().parent().parent().playKeyframe({
          name: 'rotate', // name of the keyframe you want to bind to the selected element
          duration: 90, // [optional, default: 0, in ms] how long you want it to last in     milliseconds
          timingFunction: 'linear', // [optional, default: ease] specifies the speed curve of the animation
          delay: 0, //[optional, default: 0, in ms]  how long you want to wait before the animation starts in milliseconds, default value is 0
          repeat: '1', //[optional, default:1]  how many times you want the animation to repeat, default value is 1
          direction: 'normal', //[optional, default: 'normal']  which direction you want the frames to flow, default value is normal
          fillMode: 'none', //[optional, default: 'forward']  how to apply the styles outside the animation time, default value is forwards
          complete: function(){} //[optional]  Function fired after the animation is complete. If repeat is infinite, the function will be fired every time the animation is restarted.
          });
          ;
      });`
```

'isSupported' of undefined'
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLMxr.jpg)
Thanks

Comment: What is the exact error message? Did you include https://github.com/Keyframes/jQuery.Keyframes?

Comment: 1. Images of text are too hard to read. 2. the image doesn't include the error (just where it happened): please put this information *in the question*.